# Converting WPF Browser App to WPF Desktop App

Tags: wpf, xaml, xbap

Without copying all the code from one project to another, is it possible to convert an XBAP browser app into a WPF forms app?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://blog.davidsandor.com/post/Convert-a-WPF-Browser-Application-project-to-a-WPF-Application.aspx

Answer (score 2):

In addition to the answer above, if you get the error "The manifest file at: XXX does not contain sufficient permissions to launch your application for debugging. ...", go into the app.manifest and comment out the applicationRequestMinimum tag, as follows:

```
<!--<applicationRequestMinimum>
  <defaultAssemblyRequest permissionSetReference="Custom" />
  <PermissionSet class="System.Security.PermissionSet" version="1" ID="Custom" SameSite="site" />
</applicationRequestMinimum>-->
```